# Favorite in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How can I say “favorite daughter” in Latin?

Would it be ventus filia or simply favore (i saw that this one could mean prostitute)

Comment: Hi Marina, we already have a question on "favorite" in Latin. Have you looked at it yet? If you still have questions after reading it, feel free to edit your question and flag it for re-opening once you've distinguished it further.