# Translation of “God’s Favorite” to Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-choice, christianity, religio

I have been trying to get “God’s favorite” translated into Latin. I’ve tried google translate English to Latin and “Dei Ventus” comes up. When I swap the languages to double check, Latin to English, I get “God’s Wind” in return. I’ve tried other translation resources online and have been unsuccessful. Can someone please help

Comment: I think the question "How do you say 'favourite' in Latin?" has been answered at least twice on Latin StackExchange.

Comment: It was answered [once](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/15000/how-do-you-say-favorite-in-latin) and then just [shut down the second time](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/20801/favorite-in-latin). Now'll be the third.

Comment: In any case, yes, _[ventus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ventus#Latin) Dei_ would tend to be read as _God's wind_, not anything to do with most beloved.

Comment: Found it. [See here for the discussion of why _ventus_ is so wrong but shows up for such an important word on Google Translate](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16768/how-good-is-the-new-version-of-google-translate/16769#16769).

Answer (score 0):

[As discussed here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/15000/how-do-you-say-favorite-in-latin), there are many many ways depending on the shade of meaning you're going for.

The actual historical answer for 'beloved of the G-d of Abraham' is [**Iedidia**](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/R_P_Sebastiani_Barradii_Olisiponensis_Co/g1CDcQKC0vAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=iedidia&pg=PA162&printsec=frontcover) (ידידיה, *Yĕḏîḏĕyâ*, "Jedidiah"), because discussion of Jewish ideas would've been done with reference to Hebrew or Greek. As it happens, though, when that name shows up at 2 Sam. 12:25 in reference to Solomon, [Jerome's Vulgate calques it as **Amabilis Domino**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/bib/vul/sa2012.htm#025) rather than transliterating the Hebrew name, mentioning *Jah*, or using the direct Latin *Deus*. [Here is a writer in New Latin](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/R_P_Sebastiani_Barradii_Olisiponensis_Co/g1CDcQKC0vAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=iedidia&pg=PA162&printsec=frontcover) who calques it as **dilectus Deo** in reference to the same passage. The Vulgate itself uses [**dilectus a Deo**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/bib/vul/th1001.htm#004) at 1 Thess. 1:4 for the New Testament's [ἠγαπημένος ὑπὸ τοῦ Θεοῦ](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/1_thessalonians/1.htm) (*ēgapēménos hypò toũ Theoũ*).

There would be lots of other answers (including some involving *theo-*) if you were asking about the Romans' ideas within their own religion, depending on which god, how many gods, the particular aspect you wanted to emphasize, etc. or if you were asking about ecclesiastical Latin in the medieval church. Note also that the examples above are *beloved* or *pleasing to the Lord*. If you're really insisting on *favorite* meaning *preferred before all others*, grammatically you'd do that with superlative constructions. That would be uncommon and risky since it gets into deep and dicey theological waters (read *heresy* & Athenian show trials).